# How to capture angularjs smart-table updated cell values?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, buttonclick, smart-table, datarowcollection

I am using smart-table to display a grid.

The grid is editable. I want the updated grid to be captured back to the .js file.

So that I can do some manipulation on the updated values and display it in another grid.
Below is the .js code.
 $scope.rowCollection = [{ Item: "Experiment", Budget: 30, Investment: 22, Profit: 2 },
                     { Item: "Gross subs", Budget: 23, Investment: 21, Profit: 2 },
                     { Item: "Communication channel", Budget: 27, Investment: 25, Profit: 2 },
                     { Item: "Link number", Budget: 26, Investment: 19, Profit: 7 },
                     { Item: "Digital", Budget: 24, Investment: 20, Profit: 4 }];

```
$scope.globalConfig = {
    isPaginationEnabled: false,
    itemsByPage: 20,
    syncColumns: false,
};

$scope.columnCollection = [{ label: 'Item', map: 'Item',width:'50px' },
    { label: 'Budget', map: 'Budget' },
    { label: 'Investment', map: 'Investment' },
    { label: 'Profit', map: 'Profit' }];
```

On button click I want to get the edited grid and their individual cell values.

Any ideas?